# Memory leak while swiping through an array of images

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I am currently working on an app and realized that there is a memory leak.  When you look at the SecondViewController class below, you will see that the app allows the user to swipe left and right through an array of type 'Card'.  'Card' has an image property and that image is displayed each time the user swipes left or right.  I have discovered that each time the user swipes to a new photo the amount of memory used grows.  I am at a loss of how this could be happening.  When the SecondViewController class is loaded, the 'Card' array is formed in the viewDidLoad.  All we are doing is referencing that 'Card' array each time we swipe.  I am not sure where the strong reference is in my code that is causing the memory leak. Below I will post my SecondViewController Class and Card class.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, isOnProtocol {

    @IBAction func home(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var flashcardLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

    var imageIndex: Int = 0
    var itemList:[Card] = []

    func addlist(list:[String]) {
        for word in list {
            itemList.append(Card(image: UIImage(named: word)!, soundUrl: word))
        }
    }
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "changed") == true) {
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgPhoto.bottomAnchor, constant: ((view.frame.size.height) * 0.17)).isActive = true
            flashcardLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgPhoto.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        } else {
            flashcardLabel.isHidden = true
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgPhoto.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 0..<11 {
            let list: [String]

            switch i {
            case 0: list = ["lake", "lamb", "lamp", "lark", "leaf", "leash", "left", "leg", "lime", "lips", "list", "lock", "log", "look", "love", "lunch"]
            case 1: list = ["ladder", "ladybug", "laughing", "lawnmower", "lemon", "leopard", "leprechaun", "lion", "letters", "licking", "lifesaver", "lifting", "lightbulb", "lightning",
                            "listen", "llama"]
            case 2: list = ["alligator", "balance", "ballerina", "balloon", "bowling", "cello", "colors", "dollar", "elephant", "eyelashes", "family", "gasoline", "goalie", "hula", "jellyfish", "olive", "pillow", "pilot", "polar bear", "pelican", "ruler", "salad", "silly", "telephone", "television", "tulip", "umbrella", "valentine", "violin", "yellow", "xylophone"]
            case 3: list = ["apple", "ball", "bell", "bubble", "castle", "fall", "seal", "girl", "owl", "pail", "peel", "pool", "smile", "whale", "wheel"]
            case 4: list = ["planet", "plank", "plant", "plate", "play", "plum", "plumber", "plus"]
            case 5: list = ["black", "blanket", "blender", "blocks", "blond", "blood", "blow", "blue"]
            case 6: list = ["flag", "flip flop", "float", "floor", "flower", "fluffy", "flute", "fly"]
            case 7: list = ["glacier", "glad", "glasses", "glide", "glitter", "globe", "glove", "glue"]
            case 8: list = ["clam", "clamp", "clap", "claw", "clean", "climb", "clip", "cloud"]
            case 9: list = ["sled", "sleep", "sleeves", "slice", "slide", "slime", "slip", "slow"]
            case 10: list = ["belt", "cold", "elf", "gold", "golf", "melt", "milk", "shelf"]
            default: fatalError()
            }

            if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "\(i)") as? Bool ?? true {
                addlist(list:list)
            }
        }

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        imageDisplayed()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
        leftSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
        rightSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    @IBAction func memoryButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "memory", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? MemoryViewController{
            destination.returnToImage = imageIndex
        }
    }

    internal func isOn() {
        imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func Swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

            switch swipeGesture.direction {

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:

                // decrease index first
                imageIndex -= 1

                // check if index is in range
                if imageIndex < 0 {
                    imageIndex = itemList.count - 1
                }

                UIImageView.transition(with: imgPhoto, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)
                imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image
                flashcardLabel.text = itemList[imageIndex].soundUrl

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:

                // increase index first
                imageIndex += 1

                // check if index is in range
                if imageIndex > itemList.count - 1 {
                    imageIndex = 0
                }

                UIImageView.transition(with: imgPhoto, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: nil, completion: nil)
                imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image
                flashcardLabel.text = itemList[imageIndex].soundUrl

            default:
                break //stops the code/codes nothing.
            }
        }
    }

    func imageDisplayed() {
        imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image
        flashcardLabel.text = itemList[imageIndex].soundUrl
    }

    func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        let card = itemList[imageIndex]
        card.delegate = self
        card.playSound()
    }
}
```

Card class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol isOnProtocol {
    func isOn()
}

class Card: NSObject {
    var delegate: isOnProtocol!
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    var image: UIImage
    var soundUrl: String

    init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String, isActive:Bool = true) {
        self.image = image
        self.soundUrl = soundUrl
    }

    func playSound() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.delegate = self

            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
            print("play")
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

extension Card: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool){
        if let del = delegate {
            del.isOn()
        } else {
            print("the delegate is not set")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Use weak for the delegate.

Comment: Your itemList contains images (Card) so as it grows the memory keeps growing significantly. Instead let your itemList just contain word names. That way the memory rise wouldn’t be significant. It is not a memory leak when you come out of your SecondViewController you should be able to see the reduction in memory usage

Comment: With every swipe of new card A new Instance of class Card is Created but on swipe of card you are not Deallocating class That went Out with the previous card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are large expensive objects, and the system caches them when you call `image(named:)` and doesn't let go of them until it has to. Never make an array of images or of things (like your Card) that contain images. Maintain only image *names*, fetching the image only when you actually need it for display and releasing it when it no longer is to be displayed, and for fastest, noncaching access, don't fetch the actual image with `image(named:)`.

One more hint: even when you do fetch an image for display, downsize it to the minimal size needed for display, so as not to waste memory on a larger image than you need.

Comment: Also it looks like what you're trying to do might be a lot easier and be memory-managed a lot better if you used a UIPageViewController.